# How to install fresh linux distro without causing any change to home directory logins and permissions?

Tags: system-installation, permissions, username

I presently run an ubuntu 18.04lts on my dell inspiron 3541. I have two Os running on it, Ubuntu and windows10. The Ubuntu has two partitions(root and my home directory).
So now, I want to install a new Xubuntu 18.04lts to replace the Ubuntu, but I need a help on how to go about it without losing the data including my username and password, file permissions etc.

Comment: Why not just install everything XFCE, reboot and choose XFCE when logging in and then delete everything GNOME that does not want to take anything away that belongs to XFCE. If synaptic is not installed, install it, run it, select "Sections", scroll down to "destop environment xfce", select everything in the righthand pane and install. After reboot and login to XFCE, then uninstall GNOME.

Comment: I would also not recommend to install everything from scratch. If you do that, there is no warranty that user and group IDs you created on the first installation will be the same. If that happens, you will end up with messed up ownerships of files in home directory. If you created only one user, ownerships will probably be preserved. However, installing XFCE and uninstalling Gnome, as Serafim suggests, gives you the same effect with more predictable results. Don't fix it if it is not broken.

Comment: A *new install* will ignore any customization you have made to all existing installs.

Comment: Should you, however, decide to install Xubuntu or any other Linux from scratch, you have a separate `/home` partition and that makes it easy to preserve your files. If that will be your choice I can give you a recipe to follow. I have been forced to change distribution repeatedly (due to consultant jobs) so I also keep a separate `/home` partition.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Something Else" install choice, you can tell it to use your existing `home` partition. Be Very Sure to uncheck the "`Format`" box!

Your `root` partition is where your system, and its configuration files, and all the packages you've installed, and all the configuration changes you've made, etc is going to be changed. Effort is made to preserve user configuration choices, but it is not always possible.

You can preserve the state of the above. Read `man dpkg sources.list group id groups shadow; man -a passwd`.

I've found a complete, readable backup (of `root` and `home`) essential in tasks similar to yours. It's very handy to be able to
see your system as it was when it last  worked.